# Change toast to notification in status bar?

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, statusbar, toast

I make sms applictions. This is class receive sms :

```
public class TerimaSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
        smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }

        // show first message
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                    "SMS Received : " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();   

    }
}
```

How to change toast to notification in status bar? Thanks!

Comment: Google can help you with this. When you encounter specific problems, *that's* when you ask for help.

Answer (score 2):

Add this instead of your toast:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Context context = getApplicationContext();          
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(YourClass.this, YourClass.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YourClass.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "SMS Received : " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "title", "content", contentIntent);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link this will help u to achive notification:-
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android